# Graphite Derivative shows no data

Tags: graphite, grafana

Using graphite/Grafana to record the sizes of all collections in a mongodb instance. I wrote a simple (WIP) python script to do so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pymongo import MongoClient
import socket
import time

statsd_ip = '127.0.0.1'
statsd_port = 8125

# create a udp socket 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

client = MongoClient(host='12.34.56.78', port=12345)
db = client.my_DB

# get collection list each runtime
collections = db.collection_names()

sizes = {}

# main
while (1):
    # get collection size per name
    for collection in collections:
        sizes[collection] = db.command('collstats', collection)['size']

    # write to statsd
    for size in sizes:
        MESSAGE = "collection_%s:%d|c" % (size, sizes[size])
        sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (statsd_ip, statsd_port))

    time.sleep(60)
```

This properly shows all of my collection sizes in grafana. However, I want to get a rate of change on these sizes, so I build the following graphite query in grafana:

```
derivative(statsd.myHost.collection_myCollection)
```

And the graph shows up totally blank. Any ideas?

FOLLOW-UP: When selecting a time range greater than 24h, all data similarly disappears from the graph. Can't for the life of me figure out that one.

Comment: I'd need to see the data or a graph showing it, to better understand why the `derivative()` function might be failing for you. Also, please post your `storage-schemas.conf`.

Comment: Here are some screenshots of the data: [imgur album](http://imgur.com/a/NRWJr).  

For whatever reason, the order of images got screwed up, but the information is there.

Comment: Update: I think this problem originates in graphite. Graphing using the graphite web interface yields the same results seen in grafana - derivative shows an empty graph, and including a range greater than the past 24 hours shows an empty graph. I consulted #graphite on irc.freenode.net and they seemed to think it may be an aggregation problem. My storage-aggregation.conf is an empty file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: This was due to the fact that my collectd was configured to send samples every second. The statsd plugin for collectd, however, was receiving data every 60 seconds, so I ended up with `None` for most data points.

I discovered this by checking the raw data in Graphite by appending `&format=raw` to the end of a graphite-api query in a browser, which gives you the value of each data point as a comma-separated list.

The temporary fix for this was to surround the graphite query with `keepLastValue(60)`. This however creates a stair-step graph, as the value for each None (60 values) becomes the last valid value within 60 steps. Graphing a derivative of this then becomes a widely spaced sawtooth graph.

In order to fix this, I will probably go on to fix the flush interval on collectd or switch to a standalone statsd instance and configure as necessary from there.

Comment: I am having a similar situation with collecting timeout values. What do you mean by surrounding the graphite query with `keepLastValue(60)`. Could you please show the exact example? E.g. I have this query - `http://<domain>/render?width=1700&from=-2h&until=now&height=900&target=aerospike.old_statsip-10-146-210-31.service.stat_rw_timeout&title=old_latency_cumulative_not_raw` which is displaying the cumulative sum of timeouts collected every 30 seconds.

Comment: Do you apply the derivative() after applying the keepLastValue(60)?

Comment: See also here http://www.perehospital.cat/blog/graphite-getting-derivative-to-work-with-empty-data-points for a good explanation